# Do we want to participate in the Winter Bash again this year?

Tags: discussion

> Winter Bash 2014 will again be available to all sites that choose to
>   participate. We’re redesigning all the hats and adding some extra
>   features to keep things fresh and exciting.
>
> This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Users
>   will be able to see their entire hat collection on
>   winterbash2014.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing
>   page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see
>   hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option
>   available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats
>   will go back into storage.
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be
>   the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

So, do we want to participate again this year?

**Update**

It's official, we're in. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes. I think it is a lot of fun and want to do it again this year.

Comment: But of course.   I need my hat fix.  :-)

Comment: I have no idea what this is. I guess I missed it last year. Can you explain it a bit more? I went to the 2013 page. Are these like badges in a way? Thanks in Advance! BTW- Whatever it is, I am in as long I do not have to dance on tables in my underwear and a tutu. I just do not look as good as Cheech!

Comment: @closetnoc: For various achievements, you can get various hats for your profile avatar. So yes, a bit like badges in a way.

Comment: @zigojacko It must have been just ending last year when I came to this site because I slightly do remember a hat or two now that I have had some coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course. I'm very much eager to see Hats in my head :) :) Very fun and interesting to see other user's Hat :)

[image]

Comment: I thought it was not right that you did not have an up-vote! Cheers my friend.

Comment: +1 for saving a screen shot from last year

Comment: Obviously, I liked the mask and the snorkel :-).

Comment: How embarrassing, we're wearing the same hat :-) How did I miss the Boba Fett one!?

Answer (score 3):

I am in - one up-vote from the mountains where it has been snowing and single digits outside. You think I am going outside?

Comment: You're sure you're in? You have already a hat on your head :-).

Comment: @Zistoloen ;-) If I did not wear a hat, I would laser satellites and Martians with my chrome dome!!

Comment: @Zistoloen In fact, hats upon hats might be a good idea!!

Answer (score 2):

Might as well participate again hadn't we? For some members, I'm sure they'd like it as a bit of fun - if others don't want to participate, they can just keep their usual avatar (as far as I can remember)...